# Code says fields are empty, but they're not

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a form that I've taken from another page on my site, but when I tried to use it this time it comes back with "Empty fields are not allowed. Please go back and fill in the form properly." - all the fields are filled out and I can't figure out why it is returning that error. I figured an extra set of eyes might be helpful! This is my full code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['USR_LOGIN'])=="") {    header("Location:login.php");
}
include("mytcg/settings.php");
include("$header"); 
if (!$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) { 
    $select = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `$table_members` WHERE email='$_SESSION[USR_LOGIN]'");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($select)) { ?>
<h1>Claims</h1>
Please take a minute to look through the decks that have already been claimed. If you do not see it on this list, you may go ahead and claim it!<br>

    <?php
    $username = $row['name'];
    $select1 = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `donate` WHERE name='$username'");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($select1)) {
        $name1 = $row['name'];
        $claimed1 = $row['series'];
        echo $name1;
        echo $claimed1;
    } ?>
<form action="claimdonation.php?thanks" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $row['email']; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="url" value="<?php echo $row['url']; ?>" />
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td><b>Donation Type:</b></td>
<td><select name="type" size="1">
<option value="" selected="selected">- choose one -</option>
<option value="images">Deck Images</option>
<option value="buttons">Buttons</option>
<option value="badges">Badge Set</option>
<option value="stamp">Stamp Card</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>Name</b></td>
<td><input type="text" name="series" size="20" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><b>Category</b></td>
<td><select name="category" size="1">
<option value="" selected="selected">- choose one -</option>
<option value="na" >Not Applicable</option>
<?php
for ($i=1;$i<=$num_categories; $i++) {
echo "<option value=\"$i\">".$category[$i]."</option>";
}
?>
</select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Claim!">
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php } } elseif($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']=="thanks") {
if (!isset($_POST['submit']) || $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != "POST") { exit("<p>You did not press the submit button; this page should not be accessed directly.</p>"); }
else {
$exploits = "/(content-type|bcc:|cc:|document.cookie|onclick|onload|javascript|alert)/i";
$profanity = "-- taken out for bad words --";
$spamwords = "--taken out for bad words--";
$bots = "/(Indy|Blaiz|Java|libwww-perl|Python|OutfoxBot|User-Agent|PycURL|AlphaServer)/i";

if (preg_match($bots, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
exit("<h1>Error</h1>\nKnown spam bots are not allowed.<br /><br />");
}
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = trim($value);
if (empty($value)) {
exit("<h1>Error</h1>\nEmpty fields are not allowed. Please go back and fill in the form properly.<br /><br />");
}
elseif (preg_match($exploits, $value)) {
exit("<h1>Error</h1>\nExploits/malicious scripting attributes aren't allowed.<br /><br />");
}
elseif (preg_match("#$profanity#", $value) || preg_match("#$spamwords#", $value)) {
exit("<h1>Error</h1>\nThat kind of language is not allowed through our form.<br /><br />");
}
$_POST[$key] = stripslashes(strip_tags($value));
}

$id = escape_sql(CleanUp($_POST['id']));
$name = escape_sql(CleanUp($_POST['name']));
$email = escape_sql(CleanUp($_POST['email']));
$url = escape_sql(CleanUp($_POST['url']));
$type = escape_sql(CleanUp($_POST['type']));
$series = escape_sql(CleanUp($_POST['series']));
$catnum = escape_sql(CleanUp($_POST['category']));
$catname = "$category[$catnum]";

$recipient = "$tcgemail";
$subject = "Claim Form - $name";

$message = "The following member has made a claim: \n";
$message .= "Name: $name \n";
$message .= "Email: $email \n";
$message .= "URL: $url \n";
$message .= "Donation Type: $type \n";
$message .= "Series: $series \n";
$message .= "Category: $catname \n";

$headers = "From: $name \n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: <$email>";
echo "<h1>Thank you!</h1>";
echo "When you are ready to submit your donation, please do so through your member panel.<br><br>";
if(mail($recipient,$subject,$message,$headers)) {
$insert = "INSERT INTO `donate` (`name`, `claimed`, `donated`) VALUES ('$name', '$series', 'No')";
    mysqli_query($connect, $insert);
}
}
} include ("$footer"); ?>
```

Comment: As a side note: some of the variables are declared in "mytcg/settings.php"

Comment: please format your code

Comment: Just do a `var_dump( $_POST );` to see which field is empty.

Comment: Alex - What do you mean?

Comment: Accept the answer from B. Kocaman when it solved your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

while inside another while so you can't use both variable name same '$row' for inside while.
Change the variable name, like $row1

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($select)) { ?>
......
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($select1)) {
```

I hope this help.

Comment: I admire you are looking on such unformatted code. I do not spend any second on questions like this when the people are not capable to invest few more minutes to format their code properly in order the community can read it easier...